Google Charts Timeline - change hAxis text color
I am trying to customize the hAxis text color on a Timeline chart but I can't find the right parameter. Or if this is feasible with CSS, I'd be happy too.
I have tried textStyle: { color: 'white' } but this has no effect. Any idea?


body {
  background-color: #555;
}
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load("current", {
    packages: ["timeline"]
  });
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {

    var container = document.getElementById('example');
    var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    dataTable.addColumn({
      type: 'string',
      id: 'Resource'
    });
    dataTable.addColumn({
      type: 'string',
      id: 'Name'
    });
    dataTable.addColumn({
      type: 'string',
      id: 'style',
      role: 'style'
    });
    dataTable.addColumn({
      type: 'date',
      id: 'Start'
    });
    dataTable.addColumn({
      type: 'date',
      id: 'End'
    });
    dataTable.addRows([
      ['R1', 'Event 1', 'red', new Date('April 8, 2024 08:30:00'), new Date('April 8, 2024 09:30:00')],
      ['R1', 'Event 2', 'red', new Date('April 8, 2024 09:45:00'), new Date('April 8, 2024 10:15:00')]
    ]);

    chart.draw(dataTable, {
      hAxis: {
        textStyle: {
          color: 'white' // Does not work
        },
        format: 'HH:mm',
        minValue: new Date('April 8, 2024 07:30:00'),
        maxValue: new Date('April 8, 2024 18:30:00')
      }
    });
  }
</script>

<div id="example"></div>




you can use the following css selector
note the use of fill for svg elements
#example text[text-anchor="middle"] {
  fill: #ffffff;
}

see following snippet...


body {
  background-color: #555;
}

#example text[text-anchor="middle"] {
  fill: #ffffff;
}
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load("current", {
    packages: ["timeline"]
  });
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {

    var container = document.getElementById('example');
    var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    dataTable.addColumn({
      type: 'string',
      id: 'Resource'
    });
    dataTable.addColumn({
      type: 'string',
      id: 'Name'
    });
    dataTable.addColumn({
      type: 'string',
      id: 'style',
      role: 'style'
    });
    dataTable.addColumn({
      type: 'date',
      id: 'Start'
    });
    dataTable.addColumn({
      type: 'date',
      id: 'End'
    });
    dataTable.addRows([
      ['R1', 'Event 1', 'red', new Date('April 8, 2024 08:30:00'), new Date('April 8, 2024 09:30:00')],
      ['R1', 'Event 2', 'red', new Date('April 8, 2024 09:45:00'), new Date('April 8, 2024 10:15:00')]
    ]);

    chart.draw(dataTable, {
      hAxis: {
        format: 'HH:mm',
        minValue: new Date('April 8, 2024 07:30:00'),
        maxValue: new Date('April 8, 2024 18:30:00')
      }
    });
  }
</script>

<div id="example"></div>




Yeah... I thought about that too but I wonder why there is no option to customize it like other chart features. Can we not apply a CSS selector via the API either? I am not sure text-anchor="middle" is really appropriate. What if I have other texts with the same properties? I don't, at the moment, but it just doesn't sound like a failproof solution.

there is not a hAxis.textStyle option, nor any generic css options. the row labels have a text anchor of "end" and the bar labels have "start". it shouldn't be an issue within the chart itself, thus the use of #example in the css definition.

Right, Bar charts and others have the hAxis.textStyle property but the docs for Timeline doesn't seem to mention the hAxis property at all even though I use it for the format and min/max values. I am confused. Where is this documented then?

you can find additional documentation in the release notes, about options that were added / changed after the reference page was created. the other charts are part of the corechart package, whereas the timeline chart has its own package. you could also report an issue, here
